# Custom 404 page on Sitefinity 3.5

Tags: asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

How do I implement a custom 404 page on Sitefinity 3.5 using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.selarom.net/blog/2009-01-13/sitefinity_custom_404_page_with_related_links.aspx) a very detailed article by Josh (A Sitefinity MVP) that solves this. It also shows a way to provide related links on the error page. Quite a good read.